# Python - Recursive count through BST

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

so I am doing a Find Kth Largest Value in BST leetcode problem and I want to
update the k_count every time I iterate through the tree. As you can see I print the tree value and the k_count everytime I go through. It works in that I am returning the value of the tree from largest value to smallest but I want the assocaited K_count with each tree node to update respectively. That is I want the largest value to have a k_count of 1 the second largest to have a k_count of 2 the third largest a k_count of 3 etc. I know I am close but getting thrown off with the recursive stack.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

```py
# This is an input class. Do not edit.
class BST:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


def findKthLargestValueInBst(tree, k):
    k_count = 0
    result = 0
    return findhelper(tree, k, k_count, result)

def findhelper(tree, k, k_count, result):

    if tree is not None:
    
    
        findhelper(tree.right, k, k_count, result)
        print(tree.value)
        print(k_count)
        if k_count == k:
            result = tree.value
        findhelper(tree.left, k, k_count+1, result)

        return result
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input & output (expected & actual)?

Comment: Input:  "nodes": [
      {"id": "15", "left": "5", "right": "20", "value": 15},
      {"id": "20", "left": "17", "right": "22", "value": 20},
      {"id": "22", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 22},
      {"id": "17", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 17},
      {"id": "5", "left": "2", "right": "5-2", "value": 5},
      {"id": "5-2", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 5},
      {"id": "2", "left": "1", "right": "3", "value": 2},
      {"id": "3", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 3},
      {"id": "1", "left": null, "right": null, "value": 1}
    ],

Comment: Output: 22
0
20
0
17
1
15

Comment: Expected :22
1
20
2
17
3

Comment: Where 22, 20, and 17 are tree node values and 1, 2, and 3 is what I would want the k_count to be

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your attempt is that `k_count` is a *local* variable that

1. never is assigned a different value, and
2. its value is never communicated back to the caller

More concretely, whatever the first recursive call does (to walk through the right subtree), that `print(k_count)` is always going to print the value of `k_count` it had *before* that recursive call was made, simply because that recursive call is not going to affect its value.

Again, each recursive execution of the function will get its **own** `k_count` variable, that is not related to any other `k_count` variable that exists in the call stack.

What you really want, is that when the first recursive call returns to the caller (and has visited the right subtree) that `k_count` will represent the number of nodes that were visited during that recursive call. But for that you would have to pass a *reference* to a *single* `k_count` attribute somewhere, or have the updated value *returned* by the recursive function.

But I would suggest to do this with a *generator*. It makes it so much easier to think about: perform a *reversed* inorder traversal using `yield`. Once you have that, just pull the first *k* values from that iterator and you're done.

Code:

```
def reversedInOrder(tree):
    if tree:
        yield from reversedInOrder(tree.right)
        yield tree.value
        yield from reversedInOrder(tree.left)

def findKthLargestValueInBst(tree, k):
    for value in reversedInOrder(tree):
        k -= 1
        if k == 0:
            return value
```